# Laravel issue Credentials are required to create a Client

Tags: laravel, twilio

I need to test send SMS to mobile I get Credentials are required to create a Client error for My Code Here

.env

```
 TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=AC15...................
 TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=c3...................
 TWILIO_NUMBER=+1111...
```

Config\App

```
'twilio' => [
    'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'  => env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'),
    'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID' => env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'),
    'TWILIO_NUMBER'      => env('TWILIO_NUMBER')
],
```

Controller

```
$accountSid = env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
$authToken = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
$twilioNumber = env('TWILIO_NUMBER');

$client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);

try {
    $client->messages->create(
        '0020109.....',
        [
            "body" => 'test',
            "from" => $twilioNumber
            //   On US phone numbers, you could send an image as well!
            //  'mediaUrl' => $imageUrl
        ]
    );
    Log::info('Message sent to ' . $twilioNumber);
} catch (TwilioException $e) {
    Log::error(
        'Could not send SMS notification.' .
        ' Twilio replied with: ' . $e
    );
}
```

Comment: Is `Client` a class you've created or is it from a package?

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A quick read over the [environment config for Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration#environment-configuration) suggests to me that you can use the `env` method within your config files, as you are doing, but it's not necessarily available in application code. Since you are committing your environment variables to the config object, I think you need to use the `config` method instead.

```
$accountSid = config('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
$authToken = config('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
$twilioNumber = config('TWILIO_NUMBER');
```

Let me know if that helps at all.